# Inner Join creating duplicates in SQL along with Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two datasets, where I would like to join and then group by a particular column

df1

```
version host    date        name    purpose
pat     a16     12/1/2019   pat     hi
fam     a16     12/1/2019   fam     hi
emp     a16     12/1/2019   emp     hi
dan     a16     12/1/2019   dan     hi
```

df2

```
pc  size    free  date
a16 5       1     12/1/2019
a40 4       3     12/1/2019
a41 3       1     12/1/2019
```

**Desired**

```
host    date        purpose   pc    size    free
a16     12/1/2019   hi        a16   5       1
```

**Doing**

```
SELECT   
       sum(size) AS size, sum(free) AS free,
       df1.purpose, df1.date, df1.host
FROM   df1
       JOIN df2 ON
       df1.host = df2.pc AND
       df1.date = df2.date
       GROUP BY df1.purpose, df1.date, df1.host
```

The problem is that this join keeps giving me this below with the sum of size being
size 20 and free 4, when in actuality, the sum of size should be 5 and free should be 1.
I am trying to reflect the above in a query. Any suggestion is appreciated.

```
host    date        purpose    pc   size    free
a16     12/1/2019   hi         a16  5       1
a16     12/1/2019   hi         a16  5       1
a16     12/1/2019   hi         a16  5       1
a16     12/1/2019   hi         a16  5       1
```

Comment: because `df1` all four rows have same `host` and `date`, and `group by`  include `purpose`,`date`,`host` which also same across all rows, I think you want some condition with `version` or `name`?

Comment: I see, I wish to groupby the purpose column and sum...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to just want `distinct` on the records in `df1`.  That would be:

```
SELECT SUM(size) AS size, SUM(free) AS free,
       df1.purpose, df1.date, df1.host
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT df1.purpose, df1.date, df1.host
      FROM df1
     ) df1 JOIN
     df2
     ON df1.host = df2.pc AND
        df1.date = df2.date
GROUP BY df1.purpose, df1.date, df1.host;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like T. Peter says in the comments, since there are four rows being created by the join, then SUM will do 5+5+5+5=20 etc.

Maybe you could just do a DISTINCT?

```
SELECT   DISTINCT
       df2.size, df2.free,
       df1.purpose, df1.date, df1.host
FROM   df1
       JOIN df2 ON
       df1.host = df2.pc AND
       df1.date = df2.date
```

I made a [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5fc921/5) and it seems to get you what you want. Although it's hard for me to say if it is correct in all your cases.

Comment: Ok thank you. Some of my records are not being included (in my full dataset) I will keep troubleshooting. This is helpful